# Adding a scalar to a Mat object

Tags: opencv, addition, mat

So I'm trying to add a scalar value to all elements of a Mat object in openCV, however for raw_t_ubit8 and raw_t_ubit16 types I get wrong results. Here's the code.

```
Mat A;
//Initialize Mat A; 
A = A + 0.1;
```

The Matrix is initially 
[image]

The result of the addition is exactly the same matrix. This problem does not occur when I try to add scalars to raw_t_real types of matrices. By raw_t_ubit8 I mean the depth is CV_8UC1

Comment: I dont know what a raw_t_real type is (google doesn't tell me) ...  Have you tried: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#add ? It's possible the overloaded '+' operator isn't defined for all types.

Comment: by raw_t_ubit8 I mean that the Mat A is created by
A.create(sizes_height,sizes_width,CV_8UC1), and yes I've tried the add too, yields the same result.

Comment: If you created it with CV_8UC1, it cannot possibly contain the values you mention.

Comment: it contains values 100 200 and 250 on each row which are basically the equivalents of the numbers I posted with the scaling factor if 1/255 the, viewer that I use to see the results simply divides by that factor.

Comment: you can't add 0.1 (a float / double type) to an integer type. The result will always be casted to uchar (or raw_t_ubit8).

Comment: What is raw_t_*? Are these the Image data types from Mathematica LibraryLink? ( https://reference.wolfram.com/language/LibraryLink/tutorial/InteractionWithMathematica.html )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments and in @Antonio's answer, you can't add 0.1 to an integer.

If you are using CV_8UC1 matrices, but you want to work with floating points values, you should multiply by 255.

```
Mat1b A; // <-- type CV_8UC1
...
A += 0.1 * 255;
```

If the result of the operation need to be casted, as in this case, then ultimately `saturated_cast` is called.

This is equivalent to @Antonio's answer, but it results in cleaner code (at least for me).
The same code will be used, either if you sum a `double`  or a `Scalar`. A `Scalar` object will be created in both ways using:

```
template<typename _Tp> inline
Scalar_<_Tp>::Scalar_(_Tp v0)
{
    this->val[0] = v0;
    this->val[1] = this->val[2] = this->val[3] = 0;
}
```

However if you need to sum exactly 0.1 to your matrix (and not to scale it by 255), you need to convert your matrix to CV_32FC1:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main(int, char** argv)
{
    Mat1b A = (Mat1b(3,3) << 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

    Mat1f F;
    A.convertTo(F, CV_32FC1);
    F += 0.1;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you also know how saturation is handled? I think that could be useful information to add. BTW, I don't think implicit casting (`double` -> `cv::Scalar`) is necessarily cleaner code :)

Comment: If the result of the operation need to be casted, as in this case, then ultimately `saturated_cast` is called.

Comment: @Antonio I agree, added "(at least for me)" , since this is obviously opinion based. Added also the "saturated_cast" thing.

Answer (score 3):

If, as you mentioned in the comments, the contained values are scaled in the matrix to fit the integer domain 0..255, then you should also scale the scalar value you sum. Namely:

```
A = A + cv::Scalar(round(0.1 * 255) );
```

Or even better:

```
A += cv::Scalar(round(0.1 * 255) );
```

Note that cv::Scalar, as pointed out in the comments by Miki, is in any case made from a double (it's a `cv::Scalar_<double>`).
The rounding could be omitted, but then you leave the choice on how to convert your double into integer to the function implementation.
You should also check what happens when the values saturate.

[Documentation for Opencv matrix expressions](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#matrixexpressions).

Comment: I think you can avoid the `cv::Scalar(int(round(...)...))`. The multiplication is done internally on doubles, then the result is "saturated_casted" to A type. So just `A += (0.1 * 255);` should work. Can you check?

Comment: @Miki If I am not mistaken, the `operator+` for a `cv::Mat` doesn't perform a multiplication. Although I think it does for a `cv::Rect` (summing a cv::Size it's a scaling operation).

Comment: @Miki I think it will be more efficient to submit a Scalar than a double, so that values have not to be internally/temporarily converted into double.

Comment: Creating a Scalar to submit, or submit a double that is internally converted to a Scalar is the same. Also `A += 0.1*255;` is more straightforward, in my opinion.

Comment: You are also rounding and casting to int to pass the value to the Scalar, which will re-convert the int value to double internally. I'm just pointing this out because a don't think there's the need of another answer, you can just add this in yours.

Comment: @Miki First of all you are truncating, not rounding. So let's say you at least do `round(0.1*255)` (so that 0.1 can be in fact any value). Second, in any case the value is converted into a `cv::Scalar`, so I prefer to do it explicitly so that I can control the process.

Comment: you are first rounding, then truncating. Scalar uses doubles. The operator for double and Scalar is exactly the same (I checked this in the code before pointing this out).

Comment: @Miki, yes, about being the same operator you are right, I had amended my comment. You are also right about Scalar, I have amended my answer.

Comment: Glad we agree :D. I just wrote another question pointing also out that he probably need to convert to CV_32FC1. I already +1 you because your solution is, in fact, correct.

Comment: how do i do it in java? it throws error if i try this

Comment: @HaraHaraMahadevaki Try [this](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.1.0/org/opencv/core/Core.html#add-org.opencv.core.Mat-org.opencv.core.Scalar-org.opencv.core.Mat-).